# how to do mapping user to user in drupal

Tags: hooks, users, workbench

I created 4 user in my site.

```
1)contributor1     
2)contributor2    
3)validator1     
4)validator2
```

Contributor can able to create a node  and validator can able to review the node

I am using workbench module for content moderation.

My question is?

When contributor1 create a node, then he send the node to validator1 for review
and  contributor2 create a node , then he send the node to validator2 for review

So please let me know, how can I do the user wise mapping

contributor1 create node1 through content type 1  , then only node1 access only validator1 user and he can publish the content   same as
contributor2 create node2 through content type 2 , then only node2 access only validator2 user and he can publish the content..

you have any idea please let me know

Answer (score 0):

So you have 4 user roles and 2 different content types. The first 2 user roles work with content type 1 and the other 2 user roles with content type 2.

I believe you'll find the answer to your question on [this page](https://drupal.org/node/1175592) as it explains:

- How to configure Workbench Moderation states
- How to configure and check Workbench Moderation transitions for each role

So you can set additional States according to your needs but the three default States of "Draft", "Needs Review" & "Published" seem to do the job for your case. You can also set what transitions between which states should generally be available and then configure the transition permissions for every role according to your needs.

Applying those guidelines, a Contributor1 user would create a node of content type 1 (in "Draft" state), given that they have the proper content creation permission. After that, Contributor1 would not be able to do the transition to other states for that content type. On the other hand, Validator1 should be given permissions to do the transition from "Needs Review" to "Published" for content type 1.